# ThreadExecutor method

Tags: java, asynchronous, methods, executor

I want to make a method in Java 8 that allows me to execute a MongoDB query on a different thread.

For this I want to use (?)

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

Now I would normally use something like pool.execute (() ->

I want to use it like that:

Async().updateUser(x)
Async().createUser(x)
etc.

Can anyone show or hint me how to do something like that? I don't know what I need to look for.

Comment: I think what you want is a database **connection pool** (such as Apache's DBCP).

Comment: Why you don't use connection pooling like 3CPO or Hikari?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB, that's why I dont use connection pooling like 3CPO or Hikari

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968125/mongodb-connection-pooling out

Comment: I think I made a misdescription, i dont want to know how to execute a connection on a different thread (not (yet) relevant), but a query