# Database access: singleton or close

Tags: mongodb, singleton, jax-rs, database

I am working on a project for a while and I am close to finish.
However now some technical questions are coming.

So I am dealing with mongoDB and SpringData layer.

However this is not the DB which matter but more the question behind.

I am building a rest api with jaxrs. 
I decided to put all my end point in scope prototype and my services inside scope request (because some services can be used more than one time in the same request).

However comes the question of the database.
- There are some people telling me that a singleton is the best approach to have only one connection but in the other end if the traffic grows all the request will be stuck at database entry

[image]

- There is as well the solution of the closing connection. I implemented a filter which performs some processes (like renewing token if needed etc) I could plug the close connection here. But some person say that it is really costly to open a connection and close it.

I found some answers but it is more related to the client part (phone for example) and the constraint are not the same.

Comment: Use a [connection pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968125/mongodb-connection-pooling).

Answer (score 0):

from the mongodb java driver documentation http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/

> The MongoClient() instance represents a pool of connections to the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even with multiple threads.

I might be wrong but I dont think Mongo takes advantage of multiple connections (they run sequentially anyway), making them pointless