# How do you configure jndi Glassfish 4 connection to a mongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jndi, glassfish-4

I am developing a Jee7 project and would like to employ `mongoDB` as the backend database.

My jee7 application will run on `Glassfish` 4.

I wish to use the `Glassfish` 4 admin console to configure my mongoDB `jdbc` connection pool etc..

However `Glassfish` 4 doesn't list `mongoDB` in its list of supported `Database Driver Vendor`

Does this mean that you do not configure `mongoDB` in the same way as say `DB2` or `MySQL`?

I could configure `mongoDB` using a EJB singleton, but that doesn't feel correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can without [writing your own resource adapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/resources.htm#BNCJH).  First, mongodb is non-transactionable, so it's not like it needs to participate in any transaction related events.  Second, their java driver manages the connection with their own internal connection pool.

Although it would be nice to configure the resource outside of the app, in reality you should just [create a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647636/mongodb-java-driver-database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat) bean and do everything from there.

Also take a look at [producers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26085906/1686575).